# Linq aggregate deferred execution causing query to assign

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a linq query which is doing aggreagtion on db context entity.

```
var filterRange = from row in db.Venues
                       group row by true into r
                       select new
                       {
                           minRent = r.Min(x => x.Rent),
                           maxRent = r.Max(x => x.Rent),
                           minCapacity = r.Min(x => x.Capacity),
                           maxCapacity = r.Max(x => x.Capacity)
                       };

 ViewBag.mr = filterRange.Select(x => x.minRent);
 ViewBag.xr = filterRange.Select(x => x.maxRent);
```

During razor rendering mr and xr in viewbag are having the query instead of values.

**View**

```
<input type="hidden" id="mr" name="mr" value="@(ViewBag.mr)" />
```

What needs to be done to have the viewbag contaning values?

Comment: Please explain _"having the query instead of values"_. You might just want to materialize the queries here, for example by calling `.ToList()` or  `.FirstOrDefault()` on them, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @CodeCaster ViewBag.mr contains SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
 [Extent1].[K1] AS [K1], 
 MIN([Extent1].[A1]) AS [A1]
 FROM ( SELECT 
  cast(1 as bit) AS [K1], 
  [Extent1].[Rent] AS [A1]
  FROM [dbo].[Venue] AS [Extent1]
 )  AS [Extent1]
 GROUP BY [K1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]

Comment: Then show your view. And please explain what you want this query to return. If you just want to select the min and max rent from the entire table (so, two values), you should write an entirely different query.

Comment: This is how the value of viewbag is referenced in view <input type="hidden" id="mr" name="mr" value="@(ViewBag.mr)" />

Comment: `<input type="hidden" id="mr" name="mr" value="@(ViewBag.mr)" />` is wrong for a sequence. You must use a 'foreach' construct. Your version implicitly calls `ToString()` and works only for single values.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, foreach construct solved problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First (to avoid iterating the same sequence twice), you should 'materialize' the resultset from the general query:

```
var filterRange = (from row in db.Venues
                       group row by true into r
                       select new
                       {
                           minRent = r.Min(x => x.Rent),
                           maxRent = r.Max(x => x.Rent),
                           minCapacity = r.Min(x => x.Capacity),
                           maxCapacity = r.Max(x => x.Capacity)
                       }).ToList();
```

Next, you will also have to 'materialize' the resultsets from the derived queries:

```
ViewBag.mr = filterRange.Select(x => x.minRent).ToList();
ViewBag.xr = filterRange.Select(x => x.maxRent).ToList();
```

This will execute the 'big' query once, the 'small' ones then operate on the obtained resultset, so these ones are very cheap.

Comment: This one causing ViewBag.mr to have value System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Decimal]

Comment: The code is correct. Obviously there's a call to `ToString()` somewhere (maybe implicit). Could it be that your view's code is doing something strange?

Comment: I debugged controller to see what get stored in viewbag and its confirms that viewbag property value is set to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Decimal]

Comment: And that's exactly what you want! Note that you see the _type_ of the property, not its _value_...

Comment: How to get the value?

Comment: In the Watch window, type `(IList<decimal>)ViewBag.mr`.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect (and it would totally change my answer). You're overwriting the respective ViewBag value on each iteration, which makes no sense at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45047/discussion-between-sandeep-polavarapu-and-thomas-weller)

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ query returns an IEnumerable and you need to call some method to enumerate that list in order to evaluate the query.  In this case, you should add a ToArray call after each Select call.

Comment: if i put toarray call after each select call does that calls db twice? Purpose of doing aggregation in a single query is to reduce the calls

Comment: It would if you don't do something similar on the original query.  Thomas Weller has the right idea except that you should be calling ToArray rather than ToList.  I see a lot of people call ToList by default but you should only be calling ToList if you need a generic List.  An array is more efficient than a List so call ToArray by default and only call ToList if you intend to add and remove items later, which is why you'd use a List over an array in the first place.